# Why can't we accelerate to the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Why can't we accelerate to the speed of light? It's just a speed and nothing else. Universe also crossed the speed of light at the time of big bang. Is this is just a interpretation or there is any fact behind it? I am asking it as I don't know much about this theory.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2451

Comment: in my opinion higgs field make it impossible to accelerate things to the speed of light